# How to iterate through multiples charts

Tags: excel, vba, charts, excel-2010

I need to iterate and modify properties of some charts one by one, but for that I use `ActiveChart` ex.:

```
   Target_str = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).DataLabels.Item(1).Caption
   Target = CDbl(Target_str)
```

To make my charts active I try to select them one by one:

```
    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).ChartObjects.Count
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).ChartObjects(i).Chart.Select
    '...
    Next i
```

But I get the following message in debug:

```
Run-time error '1004':
Unable to get the Select property of the Chart class
```

How can I make those charts active one by one, what am I doing wrong in the above code. 
Can I use other alternative?

Comment: Rather than try to activate the chart you can just work with it directly. eg. `Set cht=ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart`. Then you can use `With cht....End With` to perform your formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).ChartObjects(i).Select
```